# How to remove space from html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix on some content that is generated by a remote server I have no control over.

Here are the contents:

```
<span>
    <span>Text 1</span> additional text1 <---- notice there is one additional space after text1
    <span>Text 2</span>
    <span>Text 3</span>
    <span>Text 4</span>
</span>
```

The problem here is I want to show:

```
Text 1 additional text1Text 2
```

instead of:

```
Text 1 additional text1 Text2
```

For some reason, the remote server generates one additional whitespace character. Is there a way to remove that space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (clicked on wrong link). Will fix shortly but this can easily be found searching on SO where this question gets asked too often.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: The problem here is additional text1 is not inside any tag.

Comment: @BonJon That's not completely true: there are encapsulating `span` tags. A CSS solution may therefore be possible.

Comment: Could be there is no space after span, but span had a margin maybe?

Comment: @Pablo no that's not the case for me. Nathaniel Ford Could you please provide an example? Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>
    <span>Text 1</span> additional text1<!--
 --><span>Text 2</span>
    <span>Text 3</span>
    <span>Text 4</span>
</span>
```

And there are many other ways to solve it as well (as linked above by Michael Victor).